# splot with mixing data and parameter

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have two curves as data points (i. e. a two sets of two-tuples).  I want to splot the surface of their weighted sum, the weight being the third axis (so like a smooth transition from one curve to the other).

Example:  If I have the functions `sin(x)` and `x**2 / 100`, I can achieve it like this:

```
set isosamples 100
splot [-10:10] [0:1] y * sin(x) + (1-y) * (x**2 / 100)
```

In my case, however, I do not have functions but values from a data file and I do not know how to combine this with an automatic running value like the weight `y` in the example above.  I tried, e.g. this, but it did not work:

```
splot [] [0:1] 'datafile' using 1:(y):(y * $2 + (1-y) * $3)
```

The error I get is `undefined variable: y` (which is clear).  I just don't know how to combine data from a data file and a running parameter.

Comment: what is the structure of your datafile(s)? 2 files with 2 columns each (x,z) or 1 file with 3 columns (x,z1,z2) or 1 file with 4 columns (x1,z1,x2,z2)? I would assume you have common x?

Comment: My datafile (just one) has three columns.  x, y1, and y2.  (x|y1) and (x|y2) are the coordinates of the two curves.  Yes, I have a common x.  And you can call the y also z, to avoid the confusion with the y from my question, right.  (And actually there are more columns in this file and my curves are something like `($2 / ($3+$4))` but I hope that won't be a problem.)

Answer (score 1):

The first idea which comes to my mind is to plot the "mixed" data into a table. I hope that there are better approaches.

**Code:**

```
### mixing of parameter and data
reset session

# create some test data
set table $Data
    plot '+' u 1:(sin($1)):($1**2/100.) w table
unset table

N = 20.0    # float number to avoid integer division
set table $Mix
    do for [i=0:N] {
        plot $Data u 1:(i/N):(i/N*$2 + (1-i/N)*$3) w table
        plot '+' u ("") every ::0::0 w table   # plot "empty line" to disconnect lines
    }
unset table

set view 48,9
set ztics 0.5
splot $Mix u 1:2:3 w l
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you need only a smooth transition, you can use `dgrid3d`

```
set table $Data
   plot '+' u 1:($1**2/100.) w table
   plot '+' u ("") every ::0::0 w table   # plot "empty line" to disconnect lines
   plot '+' u 1:(sin($1)) w table
unset table

set view 48,9
set ticslev 0

set dgrid3d 20,100 splines
splot $Data us 1:-1:2 w l
```

The [pseudocolumn](http://www.bersch.net/gnuplot-doc/plot.html#pseudocolumns) `-1` indexes the data set.
[image]

If your x data are uniform sampled, you can simplify this to

```
set table $Data
   plot '+' u ($1**2/100.):(sin($1)) w table
unset table

set dgrid3d 20,100 splines
splot $Data matrix us ($2/10-5):1:3 w l
```

[image]